# Finding rank-$1$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank, rank-1-matrices

> Let $$S = \frac{1}{12} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 10 & 1 \\ 5 & 2 & 5\\ 1 & 2 & 9\end{pmatrix}$$ Find a rank-$1$ matrix $R$ so that $$ M = S + R $$ will have the same eigenvalues as $S$ and all the diagonal elements equal.

---

I have found the eigenvalues of $S$ to be

$$ \left\{ 1, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3},\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{3} \right\}$$

So I now have
$$M = \frac{1}{12} \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 10 & 1 \\
5 & 2 & 5\\
1&2&9\\ 
\end{pmatrix} + R $$

and $M$ has eigenvalues

$$\left\{ 1, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3},\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{3} \right\}$$

How do I find the rank-$1$ matrix $R$ with diagonal elements equal?

Comment: Please clarify what "diagonal elements equal" means. Do $S$ and $R$ have the same main diagonal? Or do $S$ and $M$?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you meant the three diagonal elements of $S+R$ are equal.

Let $R = u v^\top$.  You have $5$ equations to solve for $6$ variables $u_1,u_2,u_3,v_1,v_2,v_3$ (of course there is redundancy here): the coefficients of $\lambda^0$ to $\lambda^2$ in $\det(S+R-\lambda I) - \det(S-\lambda I)$ are $0$, $S_{11} + R_{11}-S_{22} - R_{22}=0$ and $S_{11}+R_{11}-S_{33} - R_{33} = 0$.
One of the solutions is

$$ u_1 = \frac{1}{4},\; u_2 = \frac{5}{48},\; u_3 = \frac{-5}{36}, \;v_1 = 1, \;v_2 = \frac{8}{5}, \;v_3 = 3 $$